# failed to access class com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate from class com.mongodb.Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am upgrading my spring boot application from 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.6.7. In this application i am using mongodb 2.2.12.RELEASE and mongodb-java-driver 3.8.2. application build successfully but when I deploy the application I get following error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1667)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1369)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1347)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DOPE-OP-web]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoFactory' defined in class path resource [eai-app-profile.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate from class com.mongodb.Mongo (com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate and com.mongodb.Mongo are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @2c785774)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate from class com.mongodb.Mongo (com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate and com.mongodb.Mongo are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @2c785774)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate from class com.mongodb.Mongo (com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate and com.mongodb.Mongo are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @2c785774)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:319)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:308)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:304)
        at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:326)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:48)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
        ... 49 more
```

Following is the dependency i am using.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following is the code for mongoconfig

```
public class MongoConfig implements FactoryBean<MongoClientURI> {

  private String uri;

  @Value("${mongo_socketTimeout}")
  private int socketTimeout;

  @Value("${mongo_uri}")
  public void setUri(String uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
  }

  @Override
  public MongoClientURI getObject() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClientURI(uri, MongoClientOptions.builder().socketTimeout(socketTimeout));
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return MongoClientURI.class;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete pom.xml? It looks like you have some incompatible dependencies. Generally speaking, you should remove the versions from each individual `<dependency>` and allow Boot's dependency management to control the versions instead.

Comment: Hello Andy, Thanks for your comment. Yes, the problem was happening due to mongo version compatibilty. I upgraded the mongodb dependency (spring-data-mongodb) to 3.3.6, spring-data-commons to 2.7.2, mongodb-driver-core to 4.4.2, mongodb-driver-sync to 4.4.2 and problem is resolved.